# Advertise to clients of Wifi router that the WiFi internet connection is metered

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration, mobile-hotspot

Is it possible to have a Wifi router advertise that the Wifi is connected to internet over a metered connection (over a 4G usb dongle)?

I know it's possible on client to set that the connection is metered when connecting to one. But the users usually don't do that, and their devices then do high traffic by downloading updates and stuff like that. 
So I'd like the clients to know automatically, but haven't found a way to do that yet. Is there any?

Comment: You could include "Metered" in the advertised connection name ...

Comment: I'd love to see a solution to this that could *enforce* that at the client… because otherwise you're relying on people being 'nice' & let's face it, they're not when they think they're reasonably anonymous ;)

Comment: I was thinking about enforcing too. I was concerned about automatic updates which people don't even know they are downloading. Just adding "Metered" to connection name wouldn't make a difference, to stop this happening, the people would have to set their connection as metered and most of them don't even know what it means or how to do that.

Comment: If you are going to enforce it, just impose QoS/quotas. There is no universal way getting WIFI clients to treat a connection as entered - indeed there is no way I am aware of to tell the client its entered other then via a catch hands release portal or other human communication.